# Property 'navigateByData' does not exist on type 'Router'

Tags: jestjs

I am trying to migrate from karma jasmine to jest (angular). I am getting the following issue in component while I run npm test (jest). Same configuration works with karma and jasmine.

```
    this.router.navigateByData({ url: ['/404'], 
    data: ['User do not have permission to get 
    sites'] });
```

[image]

I have written mockRouter in spec file like below:

```
let mockRouter = {
navigate: ({ }) => { },
navigateByData: ({ }) => { }
};
```